# What gets rolled twice due to Spotter I: Particularize?

Tags: lancer-rpg

The question is pretty simple, and doesn't need much context.

> PARTICULARIZE
> When an allied character adjacent to you attacks a target and consumes Lock On, they may roll twice and choose  either result.

Relevant section on making attacks (p. 64; this is for melee attacks, but all three kinds use the same language):

> The attacker chooses a target within weapon THREAT and line of sight, then makes a melee attack roll - rolling 1d20, plus GRIT and any ACCURACY or DIFFICULTY

This seems to indicate that an attack roll includes bonuses and any accuracy or difficulty - but Spotter still doesn't explicitly specify that an *attack roll* gets rolled twice.

The question is, the ally may roll *what* twice?

- just the lock on d6?
- the entire d20+accuracy+bonuses roll?
- something else?

Comment: A Reddit thread asking the same question: [With Spotter I: Particularize what gets rolled twice?](https://www.reddit.com/r/LancerRPG/comments/qcasa2/with_spotter_i_particularize_what_gets_rolled/)

Comment: I did come from there, but found their explanations unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Roll the entire roll twice

Lock on is explained on page 70:

> Any character making an attack against a character with LOCK ON may **choose to gain +1 ACCURACY on that attack and then clear the LOCK ON condition** after that attack resolves. **This is called consuming LOCK ON.**

You don't roll any dice when you consume lock on. You add +1 ACCURACY to an attack roll. So rolling twice does not happen at this stage. It happens afterwards, when you make the attack. Accuracy is explained on page 14, under Accuracy and Difficulty:

> Each point of ACCURACY **adds 1d6 to a roll**.

The d6 itself is not a roll. You are rolling a d6 of course, but that d6 is added to a roll. Only when you attack you roll, including an extra d6 as part of the roll, and you can do so twice and pick the better result.